# Downloading a file in php doesn't work for pdf but works for text files

Tags: php, file

I am trying to force download a file in my php program under a new name (new_name). I am changing the file name but keeping the extension the same as roginal file. This is part of my  code:

```
$original_filename = "attachments/20180315.log";
$new_filename = "new_name." . pathinfo($original_filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($original_filename));
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $new_filename . '"');
header('Pragma: no-cache'); 

readfile($original_filename);
exit;
```

My download is working fine when I am downloading a text file (i.e. in example above 20180315.log is a text file). When I try to do the same with a binary file (such as pdf) I am getting an empty new_name.pdf.

Any suggestion?

Comment: header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");   try to add this header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have always found the exact headers required to be a bit messy and dependent on the browser, there are a lot of options, and you will see a lot of variations posted, so i suggest the following, but you may need to just test a number of combinations until you get it right, and i suggest  making sure you test it on as many browsers as you can.

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $new_filename . "\""); 
readfile($original_filename);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Smith. I tried your combination. still the same result. It works fine for text files, but empty file in case of binary file.

Comment: tested working locally (apache web server), binary and text files. what's the new file name? does you browser know how to handle that file? have you tried another browser? or even computer?

Comment: Hi Smith. You're absolutely right. My mistake. I accidently changed part of the original file name during the process of updating my file with your suggested combination. So the file couldn't be found and a zero volume file was downloaded. I corrected the file name and it is working fine now. Thanks a lot.